# Jinja TemplateNotFound error using webpy

Tags: python, jinja2, web.py

I have a handler class and a main class. And the handler looks for t.html instead of looking for hello.html. When I print the `t` value I get `hello` and when I insert a `t.html` file in the templates folder is works. 
There seems there is some issue with this line `render.t(params)`.

```
class Handler():
    def write(self, string):
        return string

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = template
        print t # prints correclt -> hello
        return render.t(params) # Looks for t.html instead of hello.html

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        print template
        return self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def GET(self):

        return self.render("hello")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render.t` is unrelated to a separate variable named `t`. It's more similar to `render['t']`, but you're wanting to do `render[t]`.

This depends on how your `render` is defined (which is not shown in your code). You may be able subclass it and add a `__getitem__` method which simply calls `__getattr__`

For example, using the `web.py` Template render (as opposed to jinja)

```
class my_render(web.template.render):
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.__getattr__(name)

>>> render['t']() == render.t()
>>> t = 'home.html'
>>> render[t]() == render.home()
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it working with `def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return eval('render.%s(%s)' % (template, params))`. `render['t']` did not work for some reason. I will rewrite the render function though to put all arguments outside the function call.

Comment: eval is unsafe. Use `getattr(render, t)(**params)`